# Can't get mysql results more than once

Tags: python, mysql, sql, loops

I'm trying so hard to get my socket server python script to loop every so often to check for updates in a mysql table.

The code works on the first time no problem. on the second loop and every loop after it throws errors. 

Things i've tried:

- try/catch (for multiple loops to see if ANY work)
- threading
- conn.close()
- cursor.close() (not cursor.commit() any changes so this through
  errors of course)

However, I can put the code in a stand alone file and spam running the file and it works perfectly.
It doesn't seem to like running the sql code in the same process or file (which i thought threading fixed but i guess i was wrong?)

Here is the error: (note the first line is the output i'm trying to print in a loop for testing)

```
(17, 'Default2', 1, 'uploads/2/projects/5e045c87109820.19290695.blend', '')
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\urender\serverfiles\test.py", line 7, in func
    fqueue = queuedb.checkQueue()
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\urender\serverfiles\queuedb.py", line 7, in checkQueue
    cursor = conn.cursor()
  File "C:\Users\hackn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 806, in cursor
    self.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Users\hackn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1059, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

[Finished in 6.727s]
```

Here is the basic code from the test.py:

```
import queuedb
from threading import Thread
import time

def func():
    time.sleep(5)
    fqueue = queuedb.checkQueue()
    return fqueue
    func()

fqueue = queuedb.checkQueue()
print(fqueue)

Thread(target=func).start()
```

This is from my queuedb.py:

```
from dbconnect import dbconnect
import sys

def checkQueue():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM renderqueue WHERE renderer=''"
    conn = dbconnect.conn
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    return result
```

And this is the dbconnect.py:

```
import mysql.connector
import sys
from xml.dom import minidom

def parseXML():
    try:
        xmlpath = "urender/serverfiles/dbvariables.xml"
        mydoc = minidom.parse(xmlpath)
        items = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
        dbserver = items[0].attributes['dbserver'].value
        dbuser = items[1].attributes['dbuser'].value
        dbpass = items[2].attributes['dbpass'].value
        dbname = items[3].attributes['dbname'].value
        return dbserver, dbuser, dbpass, dbname
    except:
        print("Something went wrong with the XML DATA")
        sys.exit()

dbserver = parseXML()[0]
dbuser = parseXML()[1]
dbpass = parseXML()[2]
dbname = parseXML()[3]

class dbconnect:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=dbserver, user=dbuser, passwd=dbpass, database=dbname)
```

I'm sorry for such a long post but I hope i've explained the problem well enough and given an adequate amount of info.

Comment: I want to note that i have 4 other functions that either insert or delete from the db table and they run perfectly fine in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hckm101,

As indicated by the exception, there are unread rows associated with your cursor.
To solve this, you have two solutions :

- Use a buffered cursor, replacing your code with
  `conn.cursor(buffered=True)`
- Or, retrieve every result associated to your cursor using a for loop with something like : `for row in cursor:    dosomething(row)`

For more information, there is plenty of documentation available online  ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-cursor.html))

Comment: just changed to "cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)" However, when i loop it it outputs one and finishes the loop with no recursion. am i misunderstanding how to use this?

Comment: I think my answer is unclear, I mean you can set the cursor as buffered and only fetch one result OR leave it as it is and iterate over every row. Try the second option, leave your cursor declaration as it was and iterate over rows.

Comment: SunPaz so i realized i had the function returning the value instead of printing it.. so that is why it stopped sorry for that confusion... however, i just set it to print and it works beautifully now. Thank you so much for your help.